# Reference to number types in C#?

Tags: c#, xna

I was trying to create a Tween class for general purpose use in XNA games, and I ended up stuck with a problem.

In order to be able to automatize the process the way I want to, I need to be able to store a reference to a numerical value in another class so I can modify it with each update cycle.

Is there any way to accomplish that without resorting to unsafe code / pointers?

Comment: Can you store it in an object that holds the number?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how that would work, since I want to be able to modify any kind of numerical variable. Like a general purpose Tween class, which would alter positions, rotations and offset values for different types of objects.

Comment: Thats fine, just use generics. I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: If the Tween class holds the value e.g. int but as object you can pass it by reference. Then you can cast it back to int and change its value because it was passed by reference. No unsafe code needed.

Comment: @AloisKraus The problem becomes *holding* it by reference. I'm not sure storing an int passed by reference will keep the reference (in fact, I'm pretty sure it doesn't).

Comment: You need to pass your numbers around as objects and cast it down when you want to manipulate it. It is the same approach like your Wrapper class just without an extra class.

Comment: @AloisKraus I see what you are saying now. The disadvantage there is that you lose type safety due to the down cast. It is a valid approach though.

Comment: @AloisKraus Could you elaborate a bit more on that as an answer?
I think I'm a little more comfortable with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic wrapper class, and pass that around instead. When the held property is modified, all objects with a reference to the wrapper will automatically get the new value.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

Used as:

```
Wrapper<double> myDoubleObject = new Wrapper<double>();
myDoubleObject.Value = 10;
```

Comment: This is the same size as a boxed `T`, plus it will actually work (you can control whether you replace `Value` or change the `Wrapper<T>` reference to point to a different instance).

Comment: I've tried implementing your approach, but I've stumbled upon yet another problem. Since my Tween equation methods always return a double, I end up having to cast that double to the generic type T in order to assign the value to the wrapped variable, which is obviously not possible. So I'm not sure if I implemented it right.

Comment: @MarcosBraga Updated with a usage example. Does that help? I'm not sure what you are asking. Perhaps you could edit the code into the question.